# NuGet package for Sharepoint 2013 app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-config

I work on an app for SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I created it via *New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Office/SharePoint > Apps* menu. Template is called *App for SharePoint*.

Now I want to connect to PostgreSQL, run a query and display results on my `aspx` page. So, I added NuGet package `npgsql`. Here's my `packages.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Npgsql" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Here's the code snippet from `Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Npgsql" %>
<%
    string connstring = String.Format("Server=[];Port=[];UID=[];Password=[];Database=[];");
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);      
    conn.Open();
    conn.close();
%>
```

I already added few lines to my `web.config` on the server to be able to run `C#` code (put aside security for now) :

```
<PageParserPaths>
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/*" CompilationMode="Always"   AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true" />
</PageParserPaths>
```

But when I publish my app I see *The type or namespace name 'Npgsql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*.

What do I have to do to make it work?

**EDIT**
Output window shows:

```
Active Deployment Configuration: Deploy App for SharePoint
  Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.
  Uninstall app for SharePoint:
  Retraction is in progress (00:00:00)
  Successfully uninstalled the app for SharePoint.
  Install app for SharePoint:
  Uploading the app for SharePoint...
  Installation is in progress (00:00:00)
  Installation is in progress (00:00:01)
  Installation is in progress (00:00:02)
  Installation is in progress (00:00:04)
  App was installed at http://my-app-site.
  Successfully installed app for SharePoint.
  Skipping deployment step because a post-deployment command is not specified.
```

Comment: have you try to remove the ref from the prj and buil it again? also under the packages directory you can find the dll that you need

Comment: I know that the dll is there, but why do I need it? I mean, what to do with it once I locate it? Copy somewhere?

Comment: No you don't need to copy anywhere and also if you use tfs or some source version control service you don't need to save the dll on you source control.

You have just to keep these DLLs there. Also don't touch the packages.confing file if you don't know how to works

Comment: I didn't touch it : ) The dll is right where it should be, but still, app doesn't work like it should.

Comment: Select the reference, then property, copy local = true ... do a deploy and let me know

Comment: The problem is, I have no reference in my Solution Explorer. When I want to add it (rmb on project name > add > reference > browse), I select proper dll and nothing happens.

Comment: Check what is printed into the Output window

Comment: Check my edited question.